# How to disable specific http-requests to non origin based url's?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'm trying to learn extesion development for firefox for a few days. I'm trying to create something like [RequestPolicy](https://www.requestpolicy.com/). But I'm in some trouble. What I want to do is making an extension, that disables cross-site requests. For now, I have coded something like this;

```
var httpRequestObserver = {
    observe : function(aSubject, aTopic, aData) {
    if (aTopic == "http-on-modify-request") {        

      var httpChannel = aSubject.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannel);  

      var referrerHost = httpChannel.referrer.host;
      var requestedHost = httpChannel.originalURI.host;      
      var patt = new RegExp(referrerHost);

      if ( !(patt.test(requestedHost)) ) {
          alert("Referrer Host: "+referrerHost+" Requested Host: "+requestedHost+" is NOT SAME ");
      httpChannel.cancel(Components.results.NS_BINDING_ABORTED);
      }
    }
  } 
}


var observerService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"]
                                .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);
observerService.addObserver(httpRequestObserver, "http-on-modify-request", false);
```

But, this code cancels all the requests while i just want to cancel 'requestedHost'. 
To make it clear; lets say we have a foo.com that uses an image from bar.com, when I use the code snippet above, the browser can't open foo.com, what I want to do is, open the foo.com and just disable the img from bar.com.

Thanks in advance, and sorry for my decent English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't quite clear what you are trying to achieve. According to your question you want this:

- `foo.com` => `bar.com`: block
- `foo.com` => `foo.com`: allow
- `foo.com` => `sub.foo.com`: block
- `sub.foo.com` => `foo.com`: block

The correct check here would be extremely simple:

```js
if (referrerHost != requestHost) {
  httpChannel.cancel(Components.results.NS_BINDING_ABORTED);
```

But I think that you most likely meant to allow communication within the same domain:

- `foo.com` => `bar.com`: block
- `foo.com` => `foo.com`: allow
- `foo.com` => `sub.foo.com`: allow
- `sub.foo.com` => `foo.com`: allow

To properly determine the domain name you can use [nsIEffectiveTLDService](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIEffectiveTLDService):

```js
var eTLDService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/effective-tld-service;1"]
                  .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIEffectiveTLDService);
try
{
  var referrerDomain = eTLDService.getBaseDomain(httpChannel.referrer);
  var requestDomain = eTLDService.getBaseDomain(httpChannel.originalURI);
  if (referrerDomain != requestDomain)
    httpChannel.cancel(Components.results.NS_BINDING_ABORTED);
}
catch (e)
{
  Components.utils.reportError(e);
}
```

But even here you would still have issues. Consider the user clicking a link on Google going to `foo.com` - the referrer of that request would be `google.com` while the requested domain would be `foo.com`, so your code would block it. I guess that you don't want to block top-level requests but I doubt that you can distinguish them from an observer - you would need a [progress listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Progress_Listeners) or a [content policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIContentPolicy) for that.

*Note*: You can get the desired effect with the Adblock Plus extension by adding `*$third-party` filter. This filter is known to break lots of websites however - communication across domain boundaries is more common than one would expect.